# i have a radio button that needs to send info to a database

Tags: php, database, radio-button

i have a php file where certain information is loaded in, including some radio buttons. i made it in a way that, for every set of radio buttons it makes they will get a number. that number links back to the ID in the database. every set of radio buttons is like a rating system. once you click on 1 of the 4 buttons then you will get a ranking of 0 to 3

what i want is that, the moment a user presses a radio button that it will send that information to the database.

Badge.php

```
<?php include 'headAdmin.php'; ?>

    <!-- MAIN -->
    <div class="main">
        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h3 class="page-title">Badges</h3>
                <?php

                // all badges are loaded in

                $listCount = 0;
                $starCount = 0;
                echo '<div class="row">';
                foreach ($readList as $value) {

                    // for each 6 badges a Row will be closed and opened
                    if ($listCount == 6) {
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<div class="row">';
                        $listCount = 0;
                    }
                    echo '<div class="col-md-2">';
                        echo '<div class="panel">';
                            echo '<div class="panel-body">';
                                echo '<center><img class="imageUser" src="view/img/' . $value['pathToImage'] . '.png">';
                                echo '<p>' . $value['subject_subject']. '</p> ';
                                echo '<p>' . $value['description']. '</p></center>  ';
                                echo '<hr>';
                                echo '<div class="starRating">';
                                    echo '<fieldset class="rating closeRow '.$starCount.'">';
                                        echo '<input type="radio" id="cross-'.$starCount.'" name="rating'.$starCount.'" value="0" ';
                                        if ($value['done'] == 0 || $value['done'] == null) {echo 'checked';} 
                                        echo '/><label for="cross-'.$starCount.'" title="niet"><span>&#216;</span></label>';
                                    echo '</fieldset>';
                                    echo '<fieldset class="rating starRow '.$starCount.'">';
                                        echo '<input type="radio" id="star3-'.$starCount.'" name="rating'.$starCount.'" value="3" ';
                                        if ($value['done'] == 3) {echo 'checked';}         
                                        echo '/><label for="star3-'.$starCount.'" title="3"><span>&#9733</span></label>';

                                        echo '<input type="radio" id="star2-'.$starCount.'" name="rating'.$starCount.'" value="2" ';
                                        if ($value['done'] == 2) {echo 'checked';}         
                                        echo '/><label for="star2-'.$starCount.'" title="2"><span>&#9733</span></label>';

                                        echo '<input type="radio" id="star1-'.$starCount.'" name="rating'.$starCount.'" value="1" ';
                                        if ($value['done'] == 1) {echo 'checked';}         
                                        echo '/><label for="star1-'.$starCount.'" title="1"><span>&#9733</span></label>';
                                    echo '</fieldset>';
                                    $starCount++;
                                echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';    
                    echo '</div>';

                    $listCount++;

                }
            echo '</div>';
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END MAIN CONTENT -->
    </div>
    <!-- END MAIN -->
```

im not sure how to do this. i read somewhere that you need JSON but i cant find how it works or anything that is relevant to what i need. some help would be really appreciated. if more information is needed then please ask.

some extra information

- in the headAdmin.php a database connection is already made. (called with $readlist)
- im using a bootstrap template

Comment: where are u sending the data?

Comment: im getting all information from a database and i want to send the information of the radio button back to that database

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax on radio button change something like this,

```
  $(document).on("change", ".rating", function () {
      $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: url,
              data: data,
              success: success,
              dataType: dataType
      });

  });
```